# GeoServer - Layer Groups - Layer properties cross-reference

Tags: layer, geoserver

In my Geoserver instance, I've created two layers:

1. A layer that references a Shapefile that contains the polygons of the cities in Brazil. Each city has a unique id.
2. A layer created from a database store via a "SQL View" (a Geoserver one, not a database SQL View) that maps the unique id of each city to an aggregate value (eg the number of registered users in the city).

I need to style the polygons from the first layer according to the values present on the second layer. Is it possible? I know I can import the geometries into my database, but it makes things very very very very slow.

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong problem.  I doubt styling one layer based on values in another is possible.  My advice would be to bring the data to a database and figure out how to make it faster.   If you really don't want to do that -- maybe consider merging the data you have into the SHP file and work with it there instead.  Long run, shapes in the database is much more capable and rewarding.

Comment: since you are already using a view it makes sense to add the polygons to the DB (preferably PostGIS) - add a spatial index and an index on any attribute used for styling to speed things up.